R: Remove subsequent rows after specific occurences of character by group
I have a large dataset similar to the following one.



ID
Date
Change
wage




201
04.01.2023
B-AL
900


201
01.03.2023
AL-AL
900


201
01.10.2023
AL-AL
900


201
10.11.2023
AL-B
1900


201
28.11.2023
B-AL
900


201
10.12.2023
AL-B
1905


301
03.01.2023
B-AL
1100


301
11.02.2023
AL-B
2500


301
15.04.2023
B-AL
1110


301
27.09.2023
AL-B
2506


401
02.01.2023
B-AL
700


401
28.01.2023
AL-X
0


401
10.02.2023
AL-AL
700


401
02.04.2023
AL-AL
700


401
10.05.2023
AL-B
2200


401
13.08.2023
B-AL
800



I want to calculate the average wage by each status, but with two restirctions:
First, I only want to consider statuses of each individual until the status "B-AL" is reached the second time. All rows after the second occurance of "B-AL" by each ID should not be considered in the calculation.
(I think) I solved this by creating two help variables and then filter by those with cumsum()
data <- data %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(num = row_number(),
         num2 = ifelse(change == "B-AL" & num == 2, 1, 0),
         .by = c(ID, change))

data <- data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(cumsum(num2) == 0) %>% 
  ungroup()

Now the second restiction: As soon as one ID has status "AL-X" all subseqent rows should not bne considered as well.
If I use the same approach as above I also loose the observation where "AL-X" occurs the first time. However, I want this one to be included and all subsequent ones to be excluded. After both operations the table should look like this



ID
Date
Change
wage




201
04.01.2023
B-AL
900


201
01.03.2023
AL-AL
900


201
01.10.2023
AL-AL
900


201
10.11.2023
AL-B
1900


301
03.01.2023
B-AL
1100


301
11.02.2023
AL-B
2500


401
02.01.2023
B-AL
700


401
28.01.2023
AL-X
0



After that I can calculate the average wages with summarise (first by status and then by ID)
Any help is appreciated. I am also not sure whether the first operation is sound and efficient.

All rows after the second occurance of "B-AL" by each ID should not be considered, shouldn't row 5 (and 9) be included then?

Yes, sorry for the unspecific question. I want all rows after the second occurance of "B-AL" including that line removed

Judging by the desired output you want

remove everything when "B-AL" occurred the second time including that line
and
everything removed after the first occurrence of "AL-X".

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(cumsum(Change == c("B-AL")) < 2, 
         lag(cumsum(Change == c("AL-X")), default=0) < 1, .by = ID)
   ID       Date Change wage
1 201 04.01.2023   B-AL  900
2 201 01.03.2023  AL-AL  900
3 201 01.10.2023  AL-AL  900
4 201 10.11.2023   AL-B 1900
5 301 03.01.2023   B-AL 1100
6 301 11.02.2023   AL-B 2500
7 401 02.01.2023   B-AL  700
8 401 28.01.2023   AL-X    0


Thank you! I cannot upvote your answer, since I don´t have enough reputation. But your answer did what I wanted

Following the description (instead of expected output)
library(dplyr)

foo <- function(x, vc1, vc2, vc1_limit = 2L, vc2_limit = 1) {
  vc1_count <- vc2_count <- 0L
  helper <- function(v) {
    if (v == vc1) vc1_count <<- vc1_count + 1L else if (v == vc2) vc2_count <<- vc2_count + 1L
    if (vc1_count == vc1_limit || vc2_count == vc2_limit) TRUE else FALSE
  }
  pos <- Position(helper, x)
  if (is.na(pos)) length(x) else pos
}

filter(df, row_number() <= foo(Change, vc1 = "B-AL", vc2 = "AL-X"), .by = ID)

#       ID Date       Change  wage
#  1   201 04.01.2023 B-AL     900
#  2   201 01.03.2023 AL-AL    900
#  3   201 01.10.2023 AL-AL    900
#  4   201 10.11.2023 AL-B    1900
#  5   201 28.11.2023 B-AL     900
#  6   301 03.01.2023 B-AL    1100
#  7   301 11.02.2023 AL-B    2500
#  8   301 15.04.2023 B-AL    1110
#  9   401 02.01.2023 B-AL     700
# 10   401 28.01.2023 AL-X       0

